# Coinbase python APIError: Failed to send money

Tags: python, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am trying to integrate the new [Coinbase python library](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python). I want to make send_money works. But no matter how I tried, it keeps saying

```
transaction = account.send_money(address, bitcoins)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\coinbase\model.py", line 360, in send_money
'Failed to send money')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\coinbase\error.py", line 58, in build_api_error
raise error
APIError: Failed to send money
```

My python code:

```
bitcoins = 0.0001
# address = a bitcoin wallet address
client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
account = client.get_account()
transaction = account.send_money(address, str(bitcoins))
```

I can check my balance, so `account` is working. Also, all the permissions are granted in the API settings in Coinbase website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the `response` of the error to see why the call failed. This can happen for various reasons but the error message should tell you more.

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python#error-handling

```
from coinbase.error import CoinbaseError

try:
    transaction = account.send_money(address, bitcoins)
except CoinbaseError as e:
    print e.response.text
```

Comment: Can you tell me how do I get the value of `response` and `request`? I'm pretty new to python...

Comment: @Lancelot I added an example. In your code, you should catch different errors separately. See `error.py` for all errors: https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python/blob/master/coinbase/error.py

Comment: getting the `e.response.text` shows me much more detail. Now i have fixed the issue! Thanks @jorilallo